# "Correct" way to separate numeric User ID from "id;#name" value in SP2010 Person or Group list field?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

This is for SharePoint 2010, and I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I have a list. In the list there is a "Person or Group" field, who's members are pulled from a group. So, somebody adds an item from the list and picks a name displayed in my "Reviewer" field. No problem.

Over in VS2010 (this is for a workflow, fwiw), I have this...

```
SPListItem listItem = spList.GetItemById(listItemId);
String reviewerUsername = listItem["Reviewer"].ToString();
```

But if I try to use that reviewerUsername value to populate an SPUser, it fails, and various other stabs at it also fail.

Using the debugger, I can see the value of **reviewerUsername** = "**23;#Doe, John**"

My look at the SPUser object shows I could use GetUserById() and use that "23" in the "23;#Doe, John" to get the user, and a test of this method works.

**So my question, to stay on track with the subject is, is there a specific method (as in function) I should use to extract just the numeric ID from that "23;#Doe, John" string?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use normal string method [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to split your string on ";#" and get the first part which is the ID

ex:

`string reviewerID = reviewerUsername.Split(new string[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];`

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I was guessing this was a common task and there was some js function that was already loaded up that would "officially" do the split.